# Find the degrees of separation between two OWLIndividuals with given rdfs:label values

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl, ontology, owl-api

To determine the relation between two words, I've been trying to use the SUMO ontology loaded into OWL API v4.2.4. With two known words `rdfs:label` values corresponding to the given words, how can I determine the separation between two OWLIndividuals? I've been looking at using an EntitySearcher or a Walker, but I can't seem to figure out either, as I'm quite new.

**Edit:** I've noticed that (at least within the SUMO ontology) that the value of `rdf:ID` seems to much more closely correspond to what I'm after. However, I can't seem to find much info on the topic. Any guiding info is helpful: even if it seems obvious, I may not know it.

Comment: To reformulate, you want to get the OWL individuals based on the values of the annotation property `rdfs:label`, right?

Comment: @AKSW Yes, with some way to determine separation between them and another individual (such as tracking all the parents and determining the last common parent as well as the generations between the two.)

Comment: Rdf:Id isn't a property.  It's an artifact of the rdf/xml serialization process.

Comment: For what it's worth,  it sounds likeep once you precisely define what you mean by separation, a SPARQL query over the RDF might be the easiest solution.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks for the clarification. I've managed to solve the issue another way that's somewhat different from the methods I tried in the question I've posted–I'll get around to posting my solution a little later.